# Join Table vs Array of ids: PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

Let's say I have two models, songs and users, and I want to let users favorite songs.

One way to do this would be to create a join table between users as songs, let's call it favorites.  Each row of this table would just have a user id and song id and its own id.  I have some experience with this method and it works fine as far as I know.

However, I was thinking that a second way you could implement favorites would be adding a column onto the user model that consists of an array of song ids. Each id would match a song that the user had favorited.

I'm wondering which of these solutions is preferable and why.

Comment: Join Table is the best way as it has compatible when extend your database structure further.

Comment: Could you go into more detail perhaps?  Are you saying if I added more models, a join table would be preferable?  If so, why?

Comment: If you go with join table you can index on that. But for CSV it's cannot.

Comment: @BhavikJani: They're not talking about CSV-in-a-column, PostgreSQL supports [array columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html).

Comment: Can you apply index on array type columns?

Answer (score 0):

If your site have huge amount of traffic then you should go with `materialized views` database design concept.